# I have an electron app but the print button is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, electron

I have an electron app I wrote for my website that just opens the website. My website uses jQuery data tables and I have a button that I click that opens a new tab with the table as a pdf and prints it. When I try to use the button on electron it opens a new white window and nothing shows up, but it works on my website. I'm new to electron so sorry if this is a super simple fix, but I couldn't seem to find anything online for this, maybe I'm searching incorrectly. Is there any way I can get the electron app to work with my print button. The print method I'm using is a built in jQuery function. 
My electron code:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

function createWindow () {
  let win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false
    }
  })
  win.loadURL('mywebsiteurl')
  win.webContents.openDevTools()
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)
```

And my code for the data table printing

```
table = $('#studentstable').DataTable({
                    "aaData": data,
                    "dom": 'Bfrtip',
                    "buttons": ['print'],
                    "aoColumns": [
                    { "mData": "studentid"}, 
                    { "mData": "name"},
                    { "mData": "phone"},
                    { "mData": "grade"},
                    { "mData": "category"},
                    { "mData": "totalHours"},
                    { "mData": "studentid",
                        "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
                                if(type === 'display') {
                                //data = '<a href="#" onclick="getStudentInfo('+ data + ')">Edit</a>' +
                                data = '<a href="#" onclick="addStudentActivity('+ data + ')">Add Hours</a>' +
                                '&nbsp; <a href="#" onclick="deleteStudent(' + data + ')">Delete</a>' +
                                '&nbsp; <a href="#" onclick="getStudentReport(' + data + ')">Report</a>';
                                }
                                return data;
                         }
                     }],
                     "paging":true,
                     "pageLength":20,
                     "ordering":true
               });
```

Let me know if you want me to add anything else and I can send it
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just activate the nativeWindowOpen state
will be enough

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
    function createWindow () {
      let win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
           nodeIntegration: true,
           nativeWindowOpen: true, //**** add this**
        }
      })
      win.loadURL('yoursite')
      win.webContents.openDevTools()
    }
    
    app.on('ready', createWindow)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.